# Videos not running in HTML5

Tags: html5-video

I'm trying to auto-run, un-downloadable, muted-video in the loop, on my website, I already have visited multiple relevant and similar queries here and around but none of the fixes worked for me especially for Safari, chrome is playing well. I have my HTML as

Tags in the code below I have already tried

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" width="100%" height="50%" autoplay loop muted playsinline  controlsList="nodownload" name="media">

<source src="images/portfolio/modals/work/Bookflip.mp4" type="video/mp4;codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2">

<p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

Chrome is working alright, Safari is not. I'm using Safari 12.0.2

Comment: I recently had some trouble with my background video not playing so I converted from mp4 to webm and it worked. What kind of issues are you running into?

Comment: I used multiple formats conversion inclu. mp4/mov/ogg/wmv/TS/ASF after converting to all these formats - still, Safari is not showing anything but controls (which eventually I wouldn't want to be displayed). You can say I pretty much did everything mentioned in the similar results regarding this problem - but no effect. I even changed my battery power saving settings (as I use a laptop and is suggested that Apple tries to discourage use of rich media over a laptop as it eats lots of battery).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried being less specific with the `type` value? i.e. using `type="video/mp4"` instead? This is only giving a hint to the browser of course but being so specific may cause it to not work.

Also what in particular is not working? The video doesn't play at all? The auto playing isn't working? The looping?

Comment: Yes, I have tried being less specific in fact that is where I started off - still doesn't work-  So, in particular, Safari is not showing anything at all in the place the videos are placed however Chrome, Opera and Firefox are perfectly working fine.

Comment: Does the browser console say anything at all when? Is QuickTime installed? (I assume it is, but Safari won't play mp4 videos without QuickTime) If you could send a codepen or a link I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply- Honestly, just when I was going to send you the link, it worked and then I was surprised what did I change that it worked  - just then it stopped again!!? I don't know if should claim it works or not! here is the link http://www.ferozbukht.com/3DStallDesign.html (there is a looped movies in the end) - thanks

Comment: Typical technology :D
It works fine for me on Safari 12.0.1